# В чем отличие declarative_base и DeclarativeBase?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Разбираюсь с `SQLAlchemy`. Применяю ORM, но не могу понять, в чем разница между:

`from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base`

и

`from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base`

и

`from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase`

По сути работает же одинаково, или нет? Кто знает в чем разница и какой тогда применять?